# Qt, client - server relationship

Tags: c++, qt

I am newcomer in area of network and internet,therefore want to apologize for may be stupid question. I do not understand whether there are other ways to send data from client socket to server's axcept putting data into a stream using method `QIODevice::write(QByteArray& )`. If that is the only way how server should recognize what exactly data has been sent to it ? For example, we may have `QString` message as a usual input data, but also sometimes `QString` as the name of further receiver of future data. It is possible to describe all variants but the slot connected to `readyRead()` signal seems to be of enormous
size at this case.

Eventually, is there way to direct data to some exact server's functions ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is, but it seems to me like you're asking about designing a *protocol*. I.e. some way of saying "this message contains this data" and "this other message contains that other data".

Comment: Your server and client need to know how to communicate. That is, they have to agree on a common protocol - like "I'll always send two bytes that identify the type of what' comming, then I'll send 4 bytes denoting the size of the 'thing', then the data will follow"; then you'll reply with "something in a form we also already agreed upon" etc. - or something like that.. You can't just send arbitrary "stuff" and expect the other end to guess what it is.

Comment: @JesperJuhl So protocol is just set of rules and descriptions of how data can de identified ?

Comment: @Vitya Miroshnychenko more or less, yes.

Comment: try having a look at [serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats). If you are using JSON for example, you can organize your strings in JSON objects using key-value pairs. Also note that [Qt provides support for JSON](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

Qt Solutions has a library to make Qt servers easily:

[Qt Solutions](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions)

And Json format it is a beautiful way to communicate

Answer (score 0):

You need to define comman data type both side( client and server ). before you sent data packet you should write size of data packet to first four byte of data packet. at the server side check size of data receiving from client with first four bytes. and deserialize data which you how  did you serialize at client side. I used this method a long time and there is any problem occured to today. i will give you sample code for you.

**Client Side:**

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream in(&buffer);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
in << int(0);   // for packet size 
in << int(3);   // int may be this your data type or command
in << double(4);            // double data
in << QString("asdsdffdggfh");  // 
in << QVariant("");
in << .... // any data you can serialize which QDatastream accept
in.device()->seek(0);                   // seek packet fisrt byte 
in << buffer.data().size();             // and write packet size
array = buffer.data();

this->socket->write(arr);
this->socket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

**Server Side:**

```
QDatastream in(socket);

//define this out of this scope and globally
int expectedByte = -1;



if( expectedByte < socket->bytesAvailable() && expectedByte == -1 )
{
    in >> expectedByte;
}

if(expectedByte - socket->bytesAvailable()- (int)sizeof(int) != 0){
  return;
}

// if code here, your packet received completely
int commandOrDataType;
in >> commandOrDataType;
double anyDoubleValue;
in >> anyDoubleValue;
QString anyStringValue;
in >> anyStringValue;
QVariant anyVariant;
in >> anyVariant;
// and whatever ...

// do something with above data


//you must set expectedByte = -1;
// if your proccessing doing any thing at this time there is no any data will be received while expectedByte != -1,  but may be socket buffer will be filling. you should comfirm at the begining of this function
expectedByte = -1;
```

Hope this helpfully! :)